# Search For input field on policy search screen

Tags: gosu, guidewire

On the policy search page you can search by different transactions by selecting a typecode from the Search For TypeKeyInput field. Is there a way to have the results return all transactions (cancellation, policychange, submission, etc) and not just the one selected. Is there a way to have search all functionality?

Comment: Hi iceMan33. Which pcf file?

Comment: PolicySearchScreen.pcf and the field is called Search For

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PolicySearchScreen PCF uses DatabasePolicySearchPanelSet and it uses search function in gw.search.PolicySearchCriteriaEnhancement, there you can to add the condition that you like if transaction type isn't selected

Comment: I'm not sure where to add the condition on the DatabasePolicySearchPanelSet.pcf

Comment: You  must not add the condition in DatabasePolicySearchPanelSet.pcf, you must add the condition in the Enhacement.

Comment: I am in the Enhacement but not sure how to create a condition that would return all results since it's returning IQueryBeanResult in that search() function.

Comment: I am still stuck on this one. i just want to return all transactions

Comment: Hi. I'm seeing OOTB Enhacement and the query is in a .class then you can't modify. You must do a Query.make(PolicyPeriodSummary) and add each one compare that you needs (to build your own query)

Comment: Do you have an example? Also, how can I return it all as an IQueryBeanResult?

Comment: Query.make(PolicyPeriodSummary).select()    ---   select() function return a IQueryBeanResult of Query entity, before of select you must add compare conditions.